# ob for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, server, nginx-config

Hello i am settting my django app and i got the following error

```
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

when I run this command "systemctl status nginx.service"

I got this

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-06-08 08:44:51 UTC; 1min 36s ago
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
    Process: 1878 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

and when I run "journalctl -xe"
i got following message

```
--
-- The job identifier is 1.
Jun 08 08:27:55 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01 systemd[886]: Startup finished in 133ms.
-- Subject: User manager start-up is now complete
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- The user manager instance for user 1000 has been started. All services queued
-- for starting have been started. Note that other services might still be starting
-- up or be started at any later time.
--
-- Startup of the manager took 133459 microseconds.
Jun 08 08:28:40 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01 systemd[886]: Started D-Bus User Message Bus.
-- Subject: A start job for unit UNIT has finished successfully
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A start job for unit UNIT has finished successfully.
--
-- The job identifier is 16.
Jun 08 08:28:40 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01 dbus-daemon[1019]: [session uid=1000 pid=1019] AppArmor D-Bus mediation is enabled
Jun 08 08:31:39 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01 sudo[1308]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Jun 08 08:31:44 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01 sudo[1308]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Jun 08 08:40:07 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01 sshd[979]: Received disconnect from 47.15.4.238 port 54700:11: disconnected by user
Jun 08 08:40:07 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01 sshd[979]: Disconnected from user yash 47.15.4.238 port 54700
Jun 08 08:40:48 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01 sudo[1707]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Jun 08 08:40:53 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01 sudo[1707]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Jun 08 08:44:47 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01 sudo[1875]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Jun 08 08:44:51 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01 sudo[1875]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
~
~
~
~
```

can anyone help me

~

Comment: You have a good question, but you have posted to the wrong StackEachange site. I’m voting to close this question because your question is not "Programming" related, it is more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](http://superuser.com/). Since it is specifically "server" related -- I'd start there. Or since this is Ubuntu specific on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: `/etc/securetty` seems mispelled. I'd start with looking through your nginx config files to see if they have that line. They are (generally) in /etc/nginx and mostly in /etc/nignx/conf.d